# Заменить русские строчки из одного файла на строчки из другого: найти русские строчки в файле

Tags: python, строки, list, unicode

Имеется два текстовых файла (`test.txt`,`test1.txt`). В первом находится один вариант русского перевода, а во втором - перевод для разных языков, включая русский.

```
(test.txt)
Крушите всё!
Нет! Вот, значит, до чего всё дошло…

(test1.txt)
Destroy everything!!
¡¡Destruyámoslo todo!!
Руби и круши!
Zerstört alles.
Cassez tout !
Distruggi tutto!!
Destrua tudo!!
No!! And so it has come to this…
¡¡No!! Ya hemos llegado a esto...
Нет! Вот, значит, до чего все дошло…
Nein!! Euer Ende ist nah ...
Non !! Tout ça pour en arriver là...
No!! E quindi siamo arrivati a questo...
Não!! E, assim, chegou a isso…
```

Также имеются словари с алфавитом чисел, whitespace-символов, русского и английского языков.

Вопрос заключается в том, как заменить строчки с русским языком из второго файла на строки из первого?

Вот наработки:

```
eng = [
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S',    'T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s',    't','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
'!','"','#','$','%','&','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-    ','.','/',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','`','{','|','}','~']

rus = [
'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',    'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ы','Э','Ю','Я',
'а','б','в','г','д','е','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',    'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ы','э','ю','я']

symbols = [
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
'!','"','#','$','%','&','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-    ','.','/',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','`','{','|','}','~']

srus = set(rus)
seng = set(eng)
ssym = set(symbols)
sl = lambda a,b: a.intersection(b)

a1 = []
a2 = []

with open(u'test1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as fdata, open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as sdata:
    for i,v in enumerate(fdata):
        value = [j for j in v]
        value = [j.replace('\n','') for j in value]
        svalue = set(value)

        a1.append(''.join(value))

    for i,v in enumerate(sdata):
        value = [j for j in v]
        value = [j.replace('\n','') for j in value]
        svalue = set(value)

        if sl(srus,svalue) | (sl(srus,svalue) & sl(seng,svalue)) | (sl(srus,svalue) & sl(ssym,svalue)): #если есть рус., англ. и прочие символы
            a2.append(''.join(value))
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: @jfs Нет, во втором (`test1.txt`) файле есть и русский и прочие языки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь два момента:

1. Обычно нельзя просто взять и заменить одну строку на другую в текстовом файле, не переписывая всё содержимое до конца файла. Обычное решение либо загрузить весь файл в память, изменить строчки, и переписать файл в конце целиком. Или использовать временный файл, куда пишется результат, и переименовать в конце временный файл на исходный файл
2. Определить содержит строка русский перевод или не содержит. Здесь возможны разные критерии. Для простоты будем считать, что строки с русским переводом содержат заданные символы (`rus`) и только эти строки содержат подобные символы (нет смешивания языков).

Предполагая, что порядок и число переводов для русского языка совпадает в обоих файлах:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

path = Path('multilingual.txt')
with path.open(encoding='utf-8') as multilingual_file,\
     open('russian.txt', encoding='utf-8') as russian_file, \
     NamedTemporaryFile('w', encoding='utf-8', 
                        dir=str(path.parent), delete=False) as output_file: 
     for line in multilingual_file:
         if russian(line): 
             line = next(russian_file) # replace it
         print(line.rstrip('\n'), file=output_file)
Path(output_file.name).replace(path)
```

где `russian(line)` определяет является ли `line` русским переводом:

```
def russian(line, alphabet=set(rus)):
    return not alphabet.isdisjoint(line) # содержит ли line символы из rus
```

можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
import re

russian = re.compile(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, rus))).search
```

или явные диапазоны типа:  `[\u0400–\u04FF]` (зависит от задачи, подходит ли это).

Comment: Странно, но в тексте, начиная с 2214 строчки текст начал смещаться на одну строчку и иногда просто удалял её, оставляя знаки препинания.

Comment: @CockLobster это не странно, а ожидаемо что после пары тысяч  строк может быть ошибка в файле и нарушаются предположения, необходимые для  работы кода (к примеру, неожиданный перевод строки \n). Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо более устойчивый к ошибкам формат файла использовать. К примеру пронумеровать все переводы (добавить номер перед каждым переводом). Тогда ошибки в формате в одном переводе, не окажут влияния на распознавание последующих переводов.

Comment: А может тогда разделить текст на части и тогда код будет работать?

Comment: @CockLobster код уже делит текст на части.  Код *работает* (плюс/минус баги) если ввод следует явно указанным в ответе предположениям. Если вы думаете это не так, то приведите минимальный пример входных файлов, ожидаемый вывод и что вместо этого получается, используя код в ответе, и добавьте всё это в вопрос. Если не можете ошибку во вводе локализовать, спрашивайте.